# Gradle publishing error to maven; uploadArchives

Tags: gradle

I want to publish my library github to maven central, trying to push it with **gradle uploadArchives**

I always get the same error, i've almost search everywhere but there is no clear explanation to host your library in maven central.

Error is;

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':library:androidJavadocs'.

> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\DynamicLayout-master\DynamicLayout-master\library\build\tmp\androidJavadocs\javadoc.options'
>   
>   **the log of terminal is here:** http://pastebin.com/gKU2Kkpt

**this is the lib that i try to publish it;** https://github.com/Swisyn/DynamicLayout/tree/master

Comment: Try running it with `-i` and then maybe with `-d` to get more data.